# How do I delete the suggested friends list on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I have a common name and the suggested friends list is long and I don't know most of the people on it. Is there a way to delete this list so that it doesn't load at all?

Answer (score 1):

Installing the [Facebook Annoyances Blocker list](http://facebook.adblockplus.me/en/) in [AdBlock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/en/) or [uBlock Origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/), or any similar browser extension that can use AdBlock Plus-format filter lists will block many Facebook annoyances, including the 'Suggested Friends' list.

Other alternatives are the [Social Fixer](http://socialfixer.com/) and the [F.B. Purity](http://www.fbpurity.com/) browser extensions, which allow you to customize Facebook in various ways, including removing the 'Suggested Friends' list.